# Cannot draw sprite to screen

Tags: python, module, pygame, sprite

I started creating my first pygame game that uses multiple modules(.py files) for easier 
understanding the code so here we go.

main.py

```
import pygame,sys
from Player import *
from groups import *
from constants import *
from Events import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
player = Player()
player.add_to_group()

while True:
    player.draw(screen)
    event = Event()
```

Player.py

```
import pygame
from groups import *


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([30,30])
        self.image.fill([255,0,0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move_player(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += 1
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= 1
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 1
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 1

    def add_to_group(self):
        all_sprite_list.add(self)

    def remove_from_group(self):
        all_sprite_list.remove(self)

    def draw(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,(0,0))
```

groups.py

```
import pygame
all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

constants.py

```
import pygame

size = width,heighth = 700,400
```

Events.py

```
import pygame,sys

class Event(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
```

And the result should be a red square in the top left corner representing the player.
But no matter I do it, I don't get any errors but it only just shows a blank black window.

I tried to fix it several times (like using .draw to draw the entire "all_sprite_list")
but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `update` or `flip` the display:

```
while True:
    player.draw(screen)
    event = Event()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also I recommend you to handle the events at the main loop or at least not in an init method, prehaps you can create the Events object and call a method always in the same object.

The order should be:

1. Handle events to update game state
2. Clean background `screen.fill()`
3. Draw
4. update display
5. Use Clock to keep a fps rate.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me on theese things,I completly forgot on them :D cheers